# How to make an <input type="text" />'s string/content its value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, if-statement

Here's the code:
*HTML*:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" onblur="namerr()">
<br>
<label id="name_labl">This field is required.</label>
```

*CSS*:

```
#name_labl {
    display: none;
}
```

*JavaScript*:

```
var nameForm = document.getElementById("name").value.length;
function namerr() {
                if (nameForm < 1) {
                  document.getElementById("name_labl").style.display="block";
                  document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="red";
            } else {
                  document.getElementById("name_labl").style.display="none";
                  document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="black";
            }
```

---

I tried using numerous methods, ranging from using `var name_form = document.forms["mailSender"]["name"].value.length;` instead of `document.getElementById("name").value.length;` to `if (nameForm==null || nameForm=="")` instead of `nameForm<1`.

None worked. 
You see, whatever I do, I always get the actual *value* of the `<input />`, like so – `<input type="text"` ***`value="some value"`*** `/>`. However, instead of `value`, I'm using `placeholder`. 
No matter what is the text inside the form, I will always get either "0" or simply nothing in case of `value.length` or just `.value`, respectively.

**So I decided to make the contents of the `<input type="text" />` its value and then measure the length of it to determine whether the form has been filled or not.**

**Any ideas about how to do that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value does not update automatically when it changes after you read it. You need to read it inside the function to get the newest value.

```
function namerr() {
    var nameForm = document.getElementById("name").value.length;
    if (nameForm < 1) {
         document.getElementById("name_labl").style.display="block";
         document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="red";
    } else {
          document.getElementById("name_labl").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="black";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, *THAT'S* what the OP meant.

Comment: @TheLightSabrix NEVER TURN YOUR BACK ON THE JS VIKING